# Nested Dictionary in my swift application

Tags: swift, dictionary

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGtFS.png)

how do I access these image links?

I tried print(pokemonDictionary["sprites"]["back_default"]
but I get an error
Value of optional type 'Any?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?

Comment: first you have to post code not images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
if  let sprites = pokemonDictionary["sprites"] as? [String:Any] {

      print(sprites)

   if  let backImgUrl = sprites["back_default"] as? String {

        print(backImgUrl)
    }

}
```

Also you should run function named `CallUrl` in a thread other than the main , as `Data(contentsOf:)` runs synchronously and blocks the main thread

Comment: Problem Solved! THANK YOU!